# jQuery not working in Joomla

Tags: jquery, joomla2.5

I have no idea why this isn't working, but its clearly not.

So, heres the details:

- I have jQuery Easy installed.
- I am linking to a local version of jquery-latest.min.js, and it shows up in the header
- the scripts themselves work perfectly on JSFiddle (appear on click here: http://jsfiddle.net/muWLG/19/)

  ```
  $('.mobile_menu_button').mouseover(function() {
      $('.mobile_menu_list').css('visibility', ($('#fade').css('visibility') == 'visible') ? 'hidden' : 'visible');
  });

  $('.mobile_menu_button').mouseout(function() {
      $('.mobile_menu_list').css('visibility', ($('#fade').css('visibility') == 'hidden') ? 'visible' : 'hidden');
  });
  ```

Any ideas why its not working? This is the working site here: http://dev.mediaslave.ca/tyco/

Its just a proof of concept for work, nothing exciting :D

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you happen to use Mootools? There might be a conflict with the $ alias for jQuery... see here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/ (Pete's link says something similar) - and I just took a look at your page, you are indeed using Mootools.

Comment: Hey guys

Thanks so much for the help. Unfortunately the project got shelved, so this was never solved. GOtta love that. Still though, I very much appreciate the help, and will be using your answers on future projects. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your code into

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   ...
}
```

The thing is that your code is executed before the html to be loaded. SO it can not find your `.mobile_menu_button` element. This block is a jquery function executed only once page loading is over.

When you got javascript problems, check your browser's developer console, accessible with F12 shortcut. Here, on Chrome, i got Uncaught `TypeError: Cannot call method 'mouseover' of null (index):33`.

Answer (score 0):

No expert on Joomla, but maybe this helps: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/integrating-jquery-into-joomla